# Can we detect type of Mobile(android/symbian etc) through the imei number?

Tags: android, operating-system, symbian, imei

We are doing application where we need to identify the mobile type i.e android based or symbian etc through the IMEI number of that phone. Is this possible! If so please give guidance

Comment: What have you tried? We don't do your programming work here; we help you with things you're stuck on.

Comment: This sounds too much like "Is there a jQuery plugin to detect if Javascript is enabled?" -- If you make a symbian application, the phone is most likely running symbian

Answer (score 1):

Look at this article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity

and specifically Type allocation code:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_Allocation_Code

http://www.mulliner.org/tacdb/

So, I believe it's possible (at least partially).